Bundle install stuck on devise_saml_authenticatable
Im trying to run bundle install --verbose on an existing ruby on rails project.
But the bundle is hanging on this section
1:  devise_saml_authenticatable (1.9.1) from /Users/'username'/.rbenv/versions/3.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/bundler/gems/devise_saml_authenticatable-0000/devise_saml_authenticatable.gemspec
Building native extensions. This could take a while...

Im on a mac m2 chip.
Ruby version - ruby 3.1.3p185 [arm64-darwin22]
I've read a few things saying that this could be an architecture mismatch... between arm64 and rosetta? Although im not currently on rosetta and dont believe anything has been downloaded with rosetta.
I'v tried to clear the bundle cache and also run bundle install --force with the same hang.
What things could be causing this to hang?

The devise_saml_authenticatable does not appear to have any native extensions but it does rely on nokogiri, which is a gem many people report hangs on. What happens if you juts run gem install nokogiri?
